# Is the Wi-Fi symbol always supposed to have "full connection"

Tags: wifi, system-tray

The symbol in the top bar always shows the 4 bars, when WIFI is activated. Is this normal, or should it (as on iPhone) represent the WIFI strength?

Comment: You can see Wi-Fi strength only in Wi-fi option where you can set it on or off.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is normal - it does not represent the signal strength, but only whether it's active or not. (There's also an animation when it's attempting to connect to a WiFi network)

**Edit**

This behavior was changed in the ***Windows Phone 8.1***.
Now the WiFi signal on top of screen shows the power strength as in the WiFi settings menu.

Answer (score 4):

It will always be full when connected, regardless of signal strength.
Here is a break down of the three Wi-Fi related icons in the status bar ([full list of status icons](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-us/howto/wp7/basics/what-do-the-icons-on-my-phone-mean.aspx)):

[image: Connected to a Wi-Fi network] *Connected to a Wi-Fi network. The icon is animated when your phone is trying to connect to a Wi-Fi network*.

[image: On but not connected] *Wi-Fi is turned on, but your phone isn't connected to a Wi-Fi network*.

[image: Shared connection] *Cellular data connection is shared with other devices over Wi-Fi*.